# Write MS Word Doc using itextsharp library

Tags: ms-word, itext

Can I write MS Word document using iTextSharp library? If yes, please give me sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITextSharp), iTextSharp is a .NET port of iText, a *free and open source library for creating and manipulating PDF files in Java*.

You can use it to create pdf documents, but not MS Word documents.