# Conversion from dynamically generated pdf to MS Word format in c#

Tags: itext

I am using itextsharp to convert existing aspx page to pdf format on a button click event. I am looking to further convert this dynamically generated pdf to word format. Is there a way. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write MS Word Doc using itextsharp library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758043/write-ms-word-doc-using-itextsharp-library)

Comment: I dont want to use itextsharp to convert to word. The pdf is already dynamically generated by itextsharp in button click event. Then I want to open it and convert it to word with c#.

Comment: Your only tag on this was iTextSharp, you didn't provide any code to show that you tried anything and your question was assumed to be "can this tool do XYZ" which that other post answered, all of which amounted to the votes to close. However, you can (but shouldn't) use iTextSharp to [extract some text formatting from a PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6884297/231316) and then manually write a DOCX file. Instead, you should [convert your original HTML to DOCX](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431580/231316).